# Convert number to bytes in ethersjs?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, bytes32, uint256

I have a number in javascript:

```js
const oracleResponse = 1
```

And I have a function that takes a `bytes32` as input parameters

```js
function fulfillOracleRequest(
    bytes32 _requestId,
    bytes32 _data
  )
```

I want to convert `oracleResponse` in javascript to its bytes edition so that I can call this function. How do I do this?

*Note: `const oracleResponse = ethers.utils.hexlify(1)` will not work, since this will return `0x1` which is the incorrect length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ethers` also has a padding function where it will add the zeros to make it the correct length. It looks like this

```js
const oracleResponse = ethers.utils.hexZeroPad(ethers.utils.hexlify(1), 32)
```

This will pad your result to be length 32, and allow it to be accepted by your function.